# 1st data is officeIn and 2nd data is OfficeOut.. A user can multiple enter in a day.. i want how much time in hh:mm:ss format he stay in office

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

```
1476    5   2019-03-18 09:35:06.000
1487    5   2019-03-18 13:19:53.000
1488    5   2019-03-18 13:37:40.000
1495    5   2019-03-18 15:09:38.000
1497    5   2019-03-18 15:18:26.000
1503    5   2019-03-18 17:34:46.000
1504    5   2019-03-18 17:48:23.000
1511    5   2019-03-18 19:14:51.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used LAGOVER to calculate the time difference and then used ROW_NUMBER to only calculate every second row. Then I select only the rows with a calculated value. This solution is of course quite fragile since it relies on a correct number of rows with no timestamp missing.

```
SELECT employeeID, time 
FROM (
    SELECT employeeID, 
        CASE ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by employeeId ORDER BY checktime ASC) MOD 2 
        WHEN 1 THEN null
        ELSE TIMEDIFF(checktime, LAG(checktime) over (partition by employeeId ORDER BY checktime ASC)) 
        END as Time
        FROM table1) t1
WHERE time IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: ... which rather contradicts the brief

Comment: @Strawberry not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Well, we know that there are in effect 'missing' timestamps.